# Rest API java, JSON Web token authentication : invalid signature

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jersey, jwt

In Java, I try to set up a JWT authentication on a Rest API using jersey 1.9.

I'm using a friend's code sample (his token are valid with that code) and `io.jsonwebtoken` to generate token but I keep getting an Invalid signature warning when I test them on `https://jwt.io/`.

I've done some research and tried to fix that but I'm running out of ideas.

Example of invalid token I get with that code:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIyIiwiaWF0IjoxNDg1MDI2MDgzLCJzdWIiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjkxODAvVHJvY1RvblNhdm9pci8iLCJpc3MiOiJzZXJnZW50LWNoZWYiLCJleHAiOjE1MTY1NjIwODN9.HY8S7QbOhSB22d1_Dkmtg6qCiKxQRKz9W1etMqDookw

This is the login path and the method I use to create those token :

```
import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;


import io.jsonwebtoken.JwtBuilder;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.TextCodec;
import io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.MacProvider;

import dao.UserDao;

import model.User;

@Path("/home")
public class MainController {

UserController userCtrl = new UserController();

//The not really secret key
String key = "supersecretkey";

@POST
@Path("login")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public Response Login(
        @FormParam("username") String username,
        @FormParam("password") String password){

    if (username == null || password == null) {
        return Response
                .status(Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED)
                .build();
    }

    User user = userCtrl.Authenticate(username,password);

    if (user == null) {
        return Response
                .status(Status.FORBIDDEN)
                .build();
    }

    String token = createJWT(user.getUserID()+"",user.getUserName(),"http://localhost:8080/rest_api/",TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(365));

    return Response
            .status(Status.OK)
            .entity(token)
            .build();
}

private String createJWT(String id, String issuer, String subject, long ttlMillis) {

    //The JWT signature algorithm we will be using to sign the token
    SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256;

    long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Date now = new Date(nowMillis);


    //We will sign our JWT with our ApiKey secret
    byte[] apiKeySecretBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key);
    Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(apiKeySecretBytes, signatureAlgorithm.getJcaName());


    //Let's set the JWT Claims
    JwtBuilder builder = Jwts.builder().setId(id)
                                .setIssuedAt(now)
                                .setSubject(subject)
                                .setIssuer(issuer)
                                .signWith(signatureAlgorithm, signingKey );

    //if it has been specified, let's add the expiration
    if (ttlMillis >= 0) {
    long expMillis = nowMillis + ttlMillis;
        Date exp = new Date(expMillis);
        builder.setExpiration(exp);
    }

    //Builds the JWT and serializes it to a compact, URL-safe string
    return builder.compact();
  }
}
```

---

#### Solved

I don't really know what was wrong with my secret key but I manage to validate my token by changing my key generation:

```
private static final Key secret = MacProvider.generateKey(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256);
private static final byte[] secretBytes = secret.getEncoded();
public static final String base64SecretBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretBytes);
```

Comment: I could use your `createJWT()` to create a token validated by jwt.io, so 1) you did not use the `key = "pyviJ5z14Lcvb0qG6jcnmA==";` or 2) the response has been altered in some way and you have copied a bad token. You should use `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN` , not `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`

Comment: @pedrofb : Thank you for your advice, the key was the problem even if I don't know why. Changing the key creation fixed my token.